# How to map values from column3 to column1 using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to map the values from column 3 to column 1 if there is no values in column 1, if column3 is also blank then no value will be mapped.

If Column 1 and Column 3 both are having different values then we need to map values from column3 to column1

```
column1    column2    column3

2225        India      2227
             UK        35604
32578       USA        32578
            Dubai
7528        Bhutan    
            India      37890
36756       Italy      36756
```

**Expected Output:**

```
column1    column2    column3

2227        India      2227
35604        UK        35604
38956       USA        38956
            Dubai
7528        Bhutan    
37890       India      37890
36756       Italy      36756
```

**Code i have been using :**

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].fillna(df['column3'])
```

The above Code maps the values from column 3 to column1 where column1 is NaN, But i am also looking to map the values from column3 to column1 if both the values are different.

Comment: `df['column3'].fillna(df['column1'])` ?

Comment: @anky - The above line will copy values from column 3 to column 1, But i am looking to copy the values from column3 to column1 if both the values are different or column1 value is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
mask = ((df.loc[:, "Column1"] == "") | (df.loc[:, "Column3"] != "")) & (
    ~df.loc[:, "Column3"].isna()
)
df.loc[mask, "Column1"] = df.loc[:, "Column3"]

print(df)
# Outputs
column1    column2    column3
2227        India      2227
35604        UK        35604
38956       USA        38956
            Dubai
7528        Bhutan    
37890       India      37890
36756       Italy      36756
```

Comment: Sir, The above script also Copy the NaN values from column3 to column1 , As what required is if Column1 have the values and column 3 is NaN then leave it as it is.

Comment: See my updated answer with an additional condition to deal with NaN values in 'Column3'.

Answer (score 1):

Check with `update`

```
df['column1'].update(df['column3'])
```

Comment: What would be the update in "df['column1'].update(df['column3'])" , if we need to add more condition if column 1 is having values and column3 is NaN then leave the data as it is . As mentioned in the Expected output in the Question.

Comment: @Manz When the update value is NaN , the value will not be updated, kindly check the pandas official doc~